# When is the diagonal inclusion a Hurewicz cofibration

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Given a space $X$, what conditions on $X$ can you give to ensure that the diagonal map $X\to X\times X$ is a [Hurewicz cofibration](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hurewicz+cofibration)?  (I am happy to assume that $X$ is compactly generated weak Hausdorff, or even just Hausdorf.)

More generally, given a map $f:X\to Y$, when is $X\to X\times_YX$ a Hurewicz cofibration?

Comment: This condition is called "equi-locally connected" or "locally equiconnected".  If you search for those terms you'll find some results, but I don't think that the literature is extensive.  I think Peter May and his collaborators (Elmendorf, Sigurdsson?) have used this condition in various places in connection with parametrised spectra etc. 

Answer (score 9):

The diagonal condition was used crucially in Milnor's classical paper.
Milnor, John. On spaces having the homotopy type of a CW-complex. 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 90 1959 272–280.
He gives earlier references to Fox and Serre.  In the parametrized
generalization, there is a general fiberwise NDR pair characterization
of cofibrations that applies (e.g. Lemma 5.2.4 in May and Sigurdsson,
Parametrized homotopy theory).